# tumtumtum audio streamer not working

Tags: ios, streaming, mp3

I have to play mp3 audio stream within my ios app. So I used https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit this streamer. my playing method is like this

`

```
audioPlayer = [[STKAudioPlayer alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[mutArrayMP3files count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"COUNT %lu",(unsigned long)[mutArrayMP3files count]);
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://cp2.comcities.com:1935/lakhanda/default.stream/%@",[mutArrayMP3files objectAtIndex:i]];

    NSLog(@"str %@",str);
    [audioPlayer queue:str];
   // [mutArrayMP3files removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}

[mutArrayMP3files removeAllObjects];
```

`

But its not working. I dont know why is that.

Answer (score 1):

First play STKAudioPlayer and than queue audio file to STKAudioPlayer.. try below code -

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://cp2.comcities.com:1935/lakhanda/default.stream/%@",[mutArrayMP3files objectAtIndex:0]];

    NSURL* url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:str];

    STKDataSource   *dataSource = [STKAudioPlayer dataSourceFromURL:url1];
    [audioPlayer playDataSource:dataSource withQueueItemID:[[SampleQueueId alloc] initWithUrl:url1 andCount:0]];



     for (int i=0; i<urlArr.count; i++) {
         NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://cp2.comcities.com:1935/lakhanda/default.stream/%@",[mutArrayMP3files objectAtIndex:0]];

         NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
         STKDataSource* dataSource = [STKAudioPlayer dataSourceFromURL:url];
         [audioPlayer queueDataSource:dataSource withQueueItemId:[[SampleQueueId alloc] initWithUrl:url andCount:0]];
     }
```